# SQLite - Time difference in WHERE statement

Tags: sqlite

in SQLite - can I somehow calculate time difference between two timestamps in WHERE statement?

I tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (strftime("%s","now") - strftime("%s", last_update_timestamp)) > 300
```

But it doesn't seem to work :(

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the modifier `'localtime'` to `strftime()` that returns the current time:

```
where strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime') - strftime('%s', last_update_timestamp) > 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

> CAST(strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as integer) - CAST(strftime('%s', my_timestamp) as integer)

or

> SELECT (julianday(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - julianday(my_timestamp)) * 86400.0)

julianday returns the fractional number of days